# QLabel разного размера в QScrollArea

Tags: c++, qt

Делаю вывод текста в `QLabel` из базы данных. В разных случаях текста может быть много, а может вообще не быть.

Для этого в дизайнере создал `QScrollArea`, а внутрь поместил `QLabel`, в который и должен выводиться текст. При этом скролл зависит от размеров `QLabel`, даже если текста там совсем нет - скролл появляется.

Пробовал разные `sizePolicy`, устанавливал минимальные размеры `QLabel`, ничего не помогает.

Что необходимо сделать, чтобы размер `QLabel` подстраивался под размер текста?

Comment: @alexis031182 его и использую, ошибся в тексте.

Comment: Установлено ли свойство `widgetResizable` у `QScrollArea` в значение `true`?

Comment: @alexis031182 пробовал и так и так. Если `true` - то скролл вообще не появляется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот вроде, у меня получилось.

[image: Пример в дизайнере]

Идея в том, что после добавления на форму `QScrollArea`, сперва нужно добавить менеджер размещения `QLayout`, и лишь затем только `QLabel`.

Comment: Попробовал так сделать, все равно скролл зависит от размера `scrollAreaWidgetContents`, который создается вместе с `QScrollArea`.

Comment: Тогда я не вполне понимаю, что Вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Хочу, чтобы скролл зависел от наполнения `QLabel`, так как текст выводится из базы данных и может быть разного размера.

Comment: Так у меня зависит. Если текста нет или полностью влезает в область прорисовки, то полосы прокрутки исчезают. Если не хватает места по горизонтали, вертикали или в обоих направлениях, то соответствующие полоски вновь появляются.

Comment: Не понимаю, вроде делаю все так же. Здесь можно отправить ссылку на github?

Comment: Вот [проект](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/szko84huzymp3uj/AADNsWGHFoMzw9WA85fL1EFQa?dl=0).